# Google User serverAuthCode nil in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate the `GoogleSignIn` framework in an iOS app and also authenticate an user on a server. I managed to log in the user, but in the `- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error` delegate method, `user.serverAuthCode` is `nil`, and I need to pass this server authentication code to, uhm, authenticate the user on the server.

I read [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access) and it states that I have to set the `serverClientID` property of the `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance]`, but **nowhere** is it stated where do I find this "server client id". I ran tests with all the keys in the world to no avail.

I then found out [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id) which looks like it's trying to tell us where to find this magical id, but it's using poor wording and didn't help. I do have OAuth2 credentials with type `Web application`, but:

1. They are used for the web (client) app, that corresponds to my iOS app, which also communicates with the server
2. I tried using it, and it didn't work.

Did anyone manage to successfully escape from the Google *(poor)* documentation's clutches?

Comment: just add [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = "Client_ID" in AppDelegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **NOT** running it in the simulator :)

Comment: It happens on device for me too.. the serverAuthCode is nil

Comment: Not sure why others downvote. It was exactly my case. I am working with Xamarin.

Comment: I was using the iPhone 5S simulator (with iOS 8.4) and it would not give me a non-nil `serverAuthCode`. Switching to device fixed it. Does anyone know why simulator isn't working here?

Comment: What if I am stuck using the simulator?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan, No idea. Things might have changed since 2016. Do the other answers help you?

Comment: Hmm signing out seems to work, but shouldn't have been nil in the first place. Strange simulator bug probably, still exists in 2018.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make sure `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID` property is set; the value can be found in Google API Console.

Also, if you got `user.serverAuthCode` with `nil` value, make sure you called `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];` before any subsequent attempts. Otherwise `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance]` seems to remember previous configuration.

I have no problem getting the `serverAuthCode` in the simulator.

Comment: The `signOut` part worked. Make sure to sign out before you try new code.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID` is the same as `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID`.
Solved by setting `serverClientId` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can find client_id in the plist, and
server_client_id you can find through the API console manager.

You have to delete the app first, then try doing it again, simulator or device, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this configuration to get a `serverAuthCode` that is not `nil`:

```
NSError *configureError;

[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];

NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"88.....apps.googleusercontent.com";
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = @"88.....apps.googleusercontent.com" ;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[@"email", @"profile"];
```

Where:

- `clientID` uses the value of `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` from `GoogleService-Info.plist`.
- `serverClientID` uses the corresponding value from the `Google Console`.

Comment: Is the `[GGLContext configureWithError]` required? Are the `@"email"` and `@"profile"` scopes required? (doesn't `shouldFetchBasicProfile` add those automatically?)

Answer (score -1):

Get access token from `user` instead:

```
NNString* accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server auth code is the same as the access token?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You are using auth code to get access token on server side, right? Why not directly use access token.